Are there unsolved paradoxes?
Does someone know where to find a source that states which paradoxes are still considered unsolved without a logical fact based answer?
I checked several paradoxes on chatgpt and other ai asking what the hardest ones are and not considered solved by a factual answer, and all the paradoxes it gave and checked so far were solvable by seconds to hours, by far the hardest one took me a more then day but i came up with that one myself. So im highly sceptic about them really being unsolved since im well aware im not that special haha, but still like to see if there are truly unanswered ones to try apply logic on these ones. Because i like solving em Anyone having ideas where to find which ones are actually solved and which ones not? If you know one you think is really hard also lemme try those.

The Liar has many 'solutions', but people still cannot agree on any of them. In other words, it has none, see IEP: "In conclusion, it appears that more work needs to be done in finding the best way, or the best ways, out of the Liar Paradox that will preserve the most important intuitions we have about semantics while avoiding semantic incoherence." Sorites is in the same basket.

You make a valid point. I need to define "solving" better. I mean a solved solution not nessecarily as a widely accepted answer despite that is what would likely be the outcome. I mean solving as a answer purely based on facts that explains why in reality there is no paradox but seems as if there is one without leaving potential loopholes open to be up for debate

My intuitive answer to this is: yes. Otherwise, it would be a contradiction of the definition of 'paradox.'
However, I suppose it's a matter, as others have said, of what you mean by 'solve' and also what's included in the set of all "paradoxes." I would think this set would only contain ~questions for which the answer necessarily has consequences that violate something like basic rules of formal logic.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Form of answer is method.
